# How to prove the following inequalities via logical implications?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals

I am trying to find whether $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(x^2)}{e^{x^2}} \,\mathrm{d}x$ is convergent or divergent.

Firstly, I broke the integral up into two improper integrals, namely:

- the integral from 0 to 1;
- the integral from 1 to infinity

and then finding their corresponding limits.

I am trying to use the Comparison Test, and was notified by someone that the following worked:

on $(0,1)$ the exact value of $\ln(x) < \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ AND exact value of $e^{-x^2} \le 1$.

on $(1,\infty)$, exact value of $\ln(x)<x$ and $x<2e^{x/2}$ AND $e^{-x^2}<e^{-x}$.

I am confused on why they are taking the exact value and how they could imply the above inequalities.

However, I do know how to prove for $(1,\infty)$ that e^{-x^2}

\begin{align*}
x=1 &\implies x^2>x \\
&\implies e^{x^2}>e^{x} \\
&\implies \frac{1}{e^x} > \frac{1}{e^{x^2}}
\end{align*}

but the rest I am so unsure on.

Can someone please help me prove this and explain the reason for the exect values?

Comment: Some how it won't let me add the following: for (1,inf) exact value of ln(x) < x < 2*e^(x/2) AND e^(-x^2) < e^(-x)

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your equations easier on the eyes.

Comment: Should you not have $x\gt 1\implies x^2\gt x$?

Answer (score 0):

According to Mathematica the integral is convergent and gives:
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\log \left(x^2\right)}{e^{x^2}} \mathbb dx = -\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } (\gamma +\log (4)).$$